# r data.table loop through filtered data without storing it

Tags: r, performance, loops, filter, data.table

I am about to receive a dataset with about 100,000 rows and 100 columns, some numeric, some character. I have written some code in advance using base R and dplyr but I need to heavily rely on subsetting and am hence trying to make my code faster by rewriting it in data.table. I am also concerned about memory use, so I would like to avoid storing the filtered datasets I produce in my operations.

My main operations look like this:

```
for(s in 0:2){ 
# where 0=group1, 1=group2, 2=allData

  mean(data[group!=s,][["col1"]])
}
```

where function `mean()` is just used as an example. In my actual code I run the same statistical analysis for group 1, group 2 and the whole dataset.

How can I do this efficiently using data.table? Something like a magrittr-pipes structure but fast and where the temporarily filtered data does not get stored in memory.

Hope this makes sense (I am an R beginner).

PS: happy to accept functional solutions too, although it'd be good to have a loop solution too for ease of implementation within existing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this all within the world of *data.table*:

```
## example data:
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(group = rep(1:2,each=3), col1=1:6)
```

Group by each `group` value, and apply your function `mean` to `col1` where the group does not match the current group (`group != .BY`). A second line would be needed to call the function for all the data with no grouping applied:

```
data[, data[group != .BY, mean(col1)], by=group]$V1
#[1] 5 2

data[, mean(col1)]
# [1] 3.5
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. Do you think there is a way to do it in a single call? Is there a loop solution too? My current code does everything in one loop (stat analysis and builds a matrix with all results, which are converted into a TeX table after the loop) so was hoping to keep everything in one call. PS I use `group!=` on a binary variable so that if group is not equal to 2, that means that the whole dataset is used.

Comment: The loop solution would be practically identical to what you have in your question - `for( s in c(0,1,2) ) { print(data[group != s, mean(col1)]) }` or similar.

Comment: If I have to do multiple operations for each group, is it efficient to keep filtering on some rows every time I call the data (e.g. keep writing `data[group != s, ...]` ) to avoid saving `data[group != s,]` in memory or is it so inefficient I should consider storing `data[group != s,]` ?

Comment: I'm not an efficiency/running-time expert, but I don't imagine filtering over 100,000 rows would be a big bottleneck in your operation. It's usually very fast in *data.table*

Answer (score 0):

In data.table programming...try to avoid traditional (base) conditional looping. If you have some dt, use the I and J args to filter or group. If you really need to recurse, use .SD and .SDCols references with 'lapply' inside your dt brackets.

Rdata.table programming is a different mentality than base R. This means something more than 'just another R dialect'. You really should read all the vignettes and work through the examples starting with:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html

and including:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-sd-usage.html

Another good place to start is here: https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/

If you don't spend at least some time absorbing rdata.table internals and optimizations, then you just end up driving your sports car like pickup truck. More thoughts on this:

https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.cube/library/data.table/html/datatable-optimize.html

Comment: Thank you, I am looking forward to looking deeper into data.table when not under deadline pressure, as I expect the size of my datasets for future projects to get quite large. In the meantime, would you be able to provide a coded example of how to apply those principles in this context?